# Single Server 2012 R2 - DNS service won't start

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I got called in to help a small office and found a Server 2012 R2 box that hadn't had any updates installed since 2014. Went ahead and let it update and now DNS won't start. Unfortunately this is their only server, so I can't redo DNS and let it replicate. I'm getting an Event 1000 for dns.exe:

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Application Error" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>100</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-08-13T04:56:40.000000000Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>899287</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>machine.domain.com</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>dns.exe</Data> 
  <Data>6.3.9600.19397</Data> 
  <Data>5cfbd4ea</Data> 
  <Data>ntdll.dll</Data> 
  <Data>6.3.9600.19304</Data> 
  <Data>5c7f684f</Data> 
  <Data>c0000005</Data> 
  <Data>000000000003de0e</Data> 
  <Data>1ad4</Data> 
  <Data>01d551937e633e41</Data> 
  <Data>C:\Windows\system32\dns.exe</Data> 
  <Data>C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll</Data> 
  <Data>bc1c5f80-bd86-11e9-80ef-74867af3128e</Data> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

I'm seeing similar things but with the faulting module being dns.exe for Server 2008 in my searches, but so far nothing is matching up with this particular error. I've verified that all drivers are up to date and I ran `dism /scannow` to no avail.

Comment: FYI, as a temporary fix I just restored `system32\dns.exe` from a backup and the service starts fine. Not sure if that info helps. But at least they are up and running for now.

Comment: try `sfc /scannow` instead of dism /scannow